# generating PDF using TCPDF - cannot extract embedded font

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF for generating dynamic PDFs. It works fine but since I move my generator to a new server I have a problem.

I'm getting a error when I open the pdf:

```
Cannot extract the embedded font 'AAAAAC+FreeSerif'. Some characters may not display or print correctly.
```

It displays symbols instead of text. On the old server the files are successfully generated  but on the new server all I see are symbols. Anyone has any idea why this would happen? (the files on both servers are the same!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out... the problem was that the servers php.ini had:

```
set_magic_quotes_runtime on
```

Which corrupted the binary data. Turning it off solved the problem.

Comment: I'm using the exact same server with 2 versions of my plugin that implement TCPDF. The first version of my plugin gives the right font called: NotoSans-Regular. And the other version of my plugin gives AAAAAC+NotoSans-Regular.

I'm pretty certain because I'm using the exact same server that I am doing something wrong somewhere. I'm guessing some information is printed that shouldn't be printed when setting the font. I'll try your solution, but this doesn't seem like a good workaround in the case of developing a wordpress plugin. Since it is server dependent.

Comment: @SimbaClaws: Same issue: Google Font A (`Roboto`) works fine for me, Google Font B (`KoHo`) causes the `Cannot extract the embedded font` in Acrobat, strangely it looks flawless in Acrobat viewer in browser/Chrome.

Disabling font subsetting (as `$pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);`) resolved the issue, the PDF is a few `kB` larger but readers open it fine now, which is a very small price.

Comment: $pdf->setFontSubsetting(false); this did the trick. Thanks.