# How to fix that adding a custom font in tcpdf results in dotted output?

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I want to add a custom font. I converted an otf file to ttf, and load them via:

```
$std = \TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont($frutigerStd, 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
```

These command seem to do *something* as these values are set, as `$std` will have the value `frutigerltstdcn`.

And use set them, in my extended `TCDP` class via:

```
$this->SetFont($std);
```

Yet once I open my generated pdf, Adobe Reader will declare:

```
Cannot extract the embedded font 'AAAAAC+FrutigerLTStd-Cn'.
Some characters may not display or print correctly.
```

And true enough, the result is a dotted mess:

[image: Dotted output of failed TCPDF addTTFont]

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315298/generating-pdf-using-tcpdf-cannot-extract-embedded-font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that my font was erroneous. It was generated by converting an otf font to ttf, and even though I can use that generated font within MacOS, it has issues with TCDP. Once I got the font as an actual true type file, the issue was resolved.